# Django - dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required

Tags: python, django

When I am logged out I cannot access my site anymore. Why does this happen?

I doesn't matter what view I change I cannot access the site anymore.

```
ValueError at /accounts/login/

dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/
Django Version:     3.2.5
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    

dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required

Exception Location:     /Users/lorenz/.conda/envs/netto_clone/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/context.py, line 244, in bind_template
Python Executable:  /Users/lorenz/.conda/envs/netto_clone/bin/python
Python Version:     3.10.4
Python Path:    

['/Users/lorenz/PycharmProjects/netto_clone',
 '/Users/lorenz/PycharmProjects/netto_clone',
 '/Users/lorenz/Library/Application '
 'Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/213.6777.50/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_display',
 '/Users/lorenz/.conda/envs/netto_clone/lib/python310.zip',
 '/Users/lorenz/.conda/envs/netto_clone/lib/python3.10',
 '/Users/lorenz/.conda/envs/netto_clone/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/lorenz/.conda/envs/netto_clone/lib/python3.10/site-packages',
 '/Users/lorenz/Library/Application '
 'Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/213.6777.50/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend']

Server time:    Fri, 01 Apr 2022 16:21:12 -0100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get this error message:

Make your content_processors not @login authenticated.

My view in the beginning was:

```
@login_required()
def virtualmachines(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return {"virtual_machines": virtual_machines}
    return {"virtual_machines": {}}
```

Change it to :

```
def virtualmachines(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return {"virtual_machines": virtual_machines}
    return {"virtual_machines": {}}
```